# MVC Custom Authorize Attribute to validate the current user in current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, roles

I'm use to custom authorize attribute like

```
public class AdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) && User.IsCurrentUserAdmin());
    }
}
```

how to check is action call current user or not

as an example:

```
    [OnlyYouself]
    public ActionResult ViewUser(int userId)
    {
        ...
    }
```

means userId = current  user

else redirect to previous view

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Identity 2?

Comment: yes FormsAuthenticationTicket

Answer (score 1):

You might want to build a custom attribute that looks like this:

```cs
public class AllowCurrentUserAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        return (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) && filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[Field];
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
[AllowCurrentUser(Field = "userId")]
public ActionResult ViewUser(int userId)
{
    ...
}
```

There are probably better ways to check the request properties, though. Also, you may want to have a default value of "id" for the field, assuming you use the default MVC routing. If your id field is called something else, you'll want to change it.

Comment: `[AllowCurrentUser(Field = "userId")]` doesn't work - always just string value "userId"

Answer (score 0):

```
actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity
```